# How can I get the rails router to choose controller dynamically from content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building a playlist feature that can hold different types and I need a generic url helper that would go to the a controller#action depending on the type of object passed to it.

For example:

```
remove_from_playlist_path(:playlist_id: 1, :content_id: 34)
```

My attempted routing:

```
 [:links, :medias, :documents].each do |content|    
    get 'remove_from_playlist', :controller => :content, :action => :remove_from_playlist, :type => content, :as => 'remove_' + content.to_s + 'playlist'
  end
```

In each content type controller I have a remove from playlist action that looks like this:

```
 def remove_from_playlist
    playlist = Playlist.find(params[:playlist_id])
    playlist.links.delete @link
   removed successfully!'
  end
```

How can I get the route to function properly and allow me to just pass the object and have it redirect to the correct `{type}#remove_from_playlist` with a generic url helper?

Thanks!

Comment: any errors with whatever you have tried already?

Comment: Not errors but it creates a different route for each controller instead of a dynamic one so I can't use a generic _path helper. Why the downvote?

Comment: How should the router determine to which controller to pass? There is nothing in the parameters that identifies a certain type of media - as far as I understand your method call. Do you expect the router to know or to check that a certain `content_id` belongs to a certain media type? How can that be done?

Comment: @spickerman yes. Something like that. Maybe a generic function that loads the object, and checks its type and redirects to the correct controller. Not sure the best way to do something like that.

Comment: As I understand with your question , am giving solution . Don't use any url's , just create one helper method and do the functionality . its a very clean way probably for your question .

Comment: You could use a routing constraint to load the object and then check if it is of a certain type.
You'd probably have to create a route for each type, and then add a constraint to each that only allows objects of the correct type to route to it.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

Comment: I'm currently investigating polymorphic routes. It might also be a solution: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving this the other way around.

Putting the removal from playlist on the playlist controller instead of repeating it in each content controller and using  `Object.const_get(params[:klass])` to send the right class to `@playlist.send(klass).delete`

Hopefully this will help someone with a similar architecture.